# Copy contents of a div inlcuding html tags into a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

hopefully simple question,

What I want to do is to grab the contents of my div including the html tags of any child elements and insert it into a hidden input in a form **every time I press a key in another input field**

e.g. if my div is:

```
<div><p>Hello</p></div>
```

I want to copy over:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

As a string

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        $('#hidden-input').html($('#div'));
    });
});
```

The only problem is the contents of my hidden-input contains the div and the contends of the div, e.g. it looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-input" name="foo" value="bar">
    <div> (DIV CONTENTS) </div>
</input>
```

I only want (DIV CONTENTS) from the above, no div. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden-input" name="foo" value="bar">
    (DIV CONTENTS)
</input>
```

Comment: myaaan is this HTML20 ??? :)..of what i know (HTML5) you cannot have div inside a input tag.. input tag is inline tag so should be like `<input />`..there is end tag in input..

Comment: `</input>` really? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: What are you trying to achieve???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply do :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
         $('#hidden-input').html($('#div').html());
     });
 });
```

Comment: really .. you gave an answer for this.. did u notice the input tag ?? :)

Comment: Ahh, you got to this before me. :P

Answer (score 0):

`</input>` is an invalid end-of-input tag. Inputs are self enclosing tags so there's no need to `</` so you can realize that input has no HTML content, rather a **`value=""`**

therefore I suggest you to use a hidden `<textarea id="hidden-input"></textarea>` element

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready 
    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var copy = $('#div').html();
        $('#hidden-input').html( copy );
    });
});
```

---

What I don't understand from your question is:

> every time I press a key in another input field

in you have multiple input fields, than don't use `ID` in `$('#textarea').keyup(`
but rather a common className.

Here is a demo from exactly you were asking for (or at least how you explained it)

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iROZEZ/1/edit)**

### which makes no sense at all,

so I suggest you to reformulate your Question.

Answer (score -1):

Question is not logical. We can give a value to input field and val function is used for this

val(): This method is typically used to set the values of form fields.
http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        $('#hidden-input').val($('div').html());
    })
});
```

Comment: That's setting the `value` of the input. He wants to set the inner text of the input (which isn't logical anyway, but still.)

Comment: We can give a value to form input fields. Html function is for elements like div or span.